# How to display Admob Interstitial every time a Button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

I'm a BEGINNER when it comes to Android Development. This is my first application. I would like to know how to display a Admob interstitial ad every time a button is pressed. Here is my code :

```
package hamza.guideforx.com.guideforx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.Bdisplay) ;

    {
        Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}

      public void onButton1(View v1) {
          if (v1.getId() == R.id.Button1) ;
           {
            Intent o =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page.class);
            startActivity(o);
           }

       }


public void onButton2(View v2) {
    if (v2.getId() == R.id.Button2) ;
    {
        Intent q =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page2.class);
        startActivity(q);
    }

   }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Nothing admob related in your code at all. Have you tried something?

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin No, I haven't tried anything yet cause I have no idea how to do it

Comment: You should really try implementing things before asking for help on Stack Overflow. The community is here to help people when they are truly stuck, or needing explanation on things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

    // set the ad unit ID
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(InterstitialAd_ID);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);


    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);    
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();    
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
        }

        public void onAdLoaded() {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            }   
        }
    });
```

on button click -

```
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I'm still beginner I have no idea where to put exactly the codes. Could you please give instructions where to put them exactly.

Comment: @HáMzàVyNøs check this - [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial)